# Python network bandwidth monitor

Tags: python

I am developing a program in python, and one element tells the user how much bandwidth they have used since the program has opened (not just within the program, but regular web browsing while the program has been opened). The output should be displayed in GTK

Is there anything in existence, if not can you point me in the right direction. It seems like i would have to edit an existing proxy script like pythonproxy, but i can't see how i would use it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 17):

For my task I wrote very simple solution using [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil):

```
import time
import psutil

def main():
    old_value = 0    

    while True:
        new_value = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_sent + psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_recv

        if old_value:
            send_stat(new_value - old_value)

        old_value = new_value

        time.sleep(1)

def convert_to_gbit(value):
    return value/1024./1024./1024.*8

def send_stat(value):
    print ("%0.3f" % convert_to_gbit(value))

main()
```

Comment: Hi ! I like it ! Very useful and simple ! I take it

Comment: Hi! old answer, but I reused it, just to find out that [`psutil.net_io_counts().bytes_sent` and `.bytes_recv`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_io_counters) are in fact already in Bytes. So, in `convert_to_gbit()`, the multiplication by `8` seems inappropriate, do you confirm?

Comment: 1 byte = 8 bits. *8 converts bytes to bits

Comment: @Joël your comment confused me for a moment :D Multiplying by 8 gives you Gigabits while not multiplying by 8 gives you Gigabytes. Just making this more clear for future readers.

Comment: @Jimilian I believe the count would be more accurate by calling `psutil.net_io_counters` once and assigning the tuple returned to a variable for read access. Calling `psutil.net_io_counters` twice accesses the `bytes_sent` and `bytes_recv` values at different times resulting in an incorrect total.

Comment: @StephenCollins Indeed, maybe I was too focused on getting Bytes for my usage...

Comment: can you pls help me, can i use the code above to get the network usage of an specified application

Answer (score 6):

```
import time

def get_bytes(t, iface='wlan0'):
    with open('/sys/class/net/' + iface + '/statistics/' + t + '_bytes', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read();
        return int(data)

while(True):
    tx1 = get_bytes('tx')
    rx1 = get_bytes('rx')

    time.sleep(1)

    tx2 = get_bytes('tx')
    rx2 = get_bytes('rx')

    tx_speed = round((tx2 - tx1)/1000000.0, 4)
    rx_speed = round((rx2 - rx1)/1000000.0, 4)

    print("TX: %fMbps  RX: %fMbps") % (tx_speed, rx_speed)
```

should be work

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. Could you please include comments and explanation along with your code, to help people to understand?

Answer (score 3):

Well, not quiet sure if there is something in existence (written in python) but you may want to have a look at the following.

1. [Bandwidth Monitoring](https://github.com/steakunderscore/Bandwidth-Monitoring) (Not really an active project but may give you an idea).
2. [Munin Monitoring](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/tree/2.0.11) (A pearl based Network Monitoring Project)
3. [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/) (written in C/C++, based on libpcap)

Also just to give you pointers if you are looking to do something on your own, one way could be to count and store packets using `sudo cat /proc/net/dev`

Answer (score 0):

A proxy would only cover network applications that were configured to use it. You could set, e.g. a web browser to use a proxy, but what happens when your proxy exits?

I think the best thing to do is to hook in lower down the stack. There is a program that does this already, `iftop`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iftop

You could start by reading the source code of `iftop`, perhaps wrap that into a Python C extension. Or rewrite `iftop` to log data to disk and read it from Python.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like WireShark (https://wiki.wireshark.org/FrontPage) do the trick? I am tackling a similar problem now, and am inclined to use `pyshark`, a WireShark/TShark wrapper, for the task. That way you can get capture file info readily.